# Prediction intervals - "VAR in levels" vs "VAR in differences"

Tags: vector-autoregression, cointegration, prediction-interval, differencing

The prediction intervals are much wider on my "VAR in differences" model than in my "VAR in levels" model. Any ideas of why this might be the case? I know there is a strong cointegration relationship between two variables. Can that explain the effect?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.